# How to align two numpy histograms so that they share the same bins/index, and also transform histogram frequencies to probabilities?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, binning, histogram2d

How to convert two datasets X and Y to histograms whose x-axes/index are identical, instead of the x-axis range of variable X being collectively lower or higher than the x-axis range of variable Y (like how the code below generates)? I would like the numpy histogram output values to be ready to plot in a shared histogram-plot afterwards.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn

n = 100  # number of bins

#datasets
X = randn(n)*.1
Y = randn(n)*.2

#empirical distributions
a = np.histogram(X,bins=n)
b = np.histogram(Y,bins=n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not use `np.histogram` if your goal is just plotting the two (or more) together. Matplotlib can do that.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist([X, Y])  # using your X & Y from question
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want the probabilities instead of counts in histogram, add weights:

```
wx = np.ones_like(X) / len(X)
wy = np.ones_like(Y) / len(Y)
```

You can also get output from `plt.hist` for some other usage.

```
n_plt, bins_plt, patches = plt.hist([X, Y], bins=n-1, weights=[wx,wy])  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note usage of `n-1` here instead of `n` because one extra bin is added by numpy and matplotlib. You may use `n` depending on your use case.

However, if you really want the bins for some other purpose, `np.historgram` gives the bins used in output - which you can use as input in second histogram:

```
a,bins_numpy = np.histogram(Y,bins=n-1)
b,bins2 = np.histogram(X,bins=bins_numpy)
```

Y's bins used for X here because your Y has wider range than X.

Reconciliation Checks:

```
all(bins_numpy == bins2)

>>>True


all(bins_numpy == bins_plt)

>>>True
```

Comment: Thanks, another question, how do i convert the y-axis of your graph from frequencies to probabilities whose max is 1? somehow normalize a and b?

Comment: @develarist Just divide the histogram by total number of elements, like this: 
a/sum(a)

Comment: I tried to normalize the frequency of the histogram into probabililities using `plt.hist([X, Y], density=True)`, but the histogram produced by `density=True` is identical to   `density=False`

Comment: No, do not do that. When you get numpy histogram a using the command 
`a, bins1 = np.histogram(X,bins=n)`
simply divide the histogram by total number of elements
`probability_dist = a/sum(a)`

Comment: but how do I graph that transformation as a histogram after? the two outputs of `np.histogram` (histogram values, and bin edges) are shaped `len(a)` and `len(a)+1`, giving a shape mismatch error if I try to plot these vectors manually after, transformed or untransormed

Comment: Oh, now I got your goal. Adding that to the answer

Comment: in your edit, how do I transform the X and Y frequencies *directly* to probabilities. Do I multiple the original, untransformed histogram values by the normalization weights `wx`?

Comment: As discussed before in comments `probability_dist = a/sum(a)`

Comment: but `plt.hist` requires weights and doesn't use the direct transformation `a/sum(a)`. How to reconcile the former, that masks the original data, and the latter, which transforms the data? I need both at the same time, not one or the other

Comment: Yeah `a,bins1 = np.histogram(X,bins=n)` is giving 101 bins instead of 100. What if we change `n` to `n-1` here ? i.e. `a,bins1 = np.histogram(X,bins=n-1)`. Does that help ?

Comment: that's not the issue of my previous comment, but  regarding `bins=n-1`, how would you know whether to remove the left or right bin edge?

Comment: `bins=n-1` will give exact 100 bins. No need to manually remove any left/right bin. Anyway I think your main issue is **reconciliation**. Also, I think I was confused because your number of elements in X and number of bins is equal. `X = randn(n)` and  `bins=n`. I am assuming that is intentional and editing the answer.