# Numpy histogram data: Why is the length of bins vector longer than the histogram values vector?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, binning

There are two outputs to `numpy.histogram`:

- `hist`: values of the histogram
- `bin_edges`: Return the bin edges `(length(hist)+1)`

both are vectors but in the example below, the second vector is of length 101, which is 1 higher than the first vector, which is length 100 :

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand, randn

n = 100  # number of bins
X = randn(n)*.1
a,bins1 = np.histogram(X,bins=n)
```

The following shape error occurs if I then try `plt.plot(bins1,a)`:

> `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (101,) and (100,)`

Why, and how do I fix the inequal shape error so I can plot the histogram?

Comment: Why are you not just using `plt.hist`?

Comment: Because i need to keep the data for normalization to probabilities of 1, not just print the graph

Comment: `pyplot.hist` returns the values of the histogram bins.

Comment: @BigBen great, but how do I *transform* the "values of the histogram bins" into normalized probabilities that have a maximum of 1 after, and *plot* those transformed values after as a new bar histogram without running into a shape mismatch error with the unchanged `bin_edges` vector? some more discussion in the comments here stackoverflow.com/questions/64648202/…

Comment: Is what you want to do is call `plt.hist()` with `density=True`?

Comment: @Timo `density` does not alter the histogram whatsoever as was discussed in the comments here, where someone says "No do not do that": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64648202/how-to-align-two-numpy-histograms-so-that-they-share-the-same-bins-index-and-al/64649670#64649670

Answer (score 2):

The unequal shapes occur because `bin_edges`, as the name implies, specifies the bin edges. Since a bin has left and right edge, `bin_edges` will have be of length `len(bins)+1`.

As already denoted in the comments, an appropriate way to plot is [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this question as well because I wanted to transform my data before doing a histogram but display the results un-transformed (eg. just keep the autogenerated bin edges). The other answers here got you most of the way but what I found was useful was to do something like this:

```
h, bin_edges = np.histogram(np.log(X), bins=100)
plt.hist(X, bins=np.exp(bin_edges))
```

Of course, you could do this manually by just choosing your bin edges originally and passing them in to `plt.hist` without using `np.histogram`. But this was nice as the automated calculations simplified some things for me.